# How to call controller method from Javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call a controller method on a button click. I created a java function for this, and now I'm stuck...

```
   using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Packaging", FormMethod.Post))      
   {%>          
       ......              
        <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave" onclick="return btnSave_onclick()" />
   }%>



    function btnSave_onclick() {

        window.open(Url.Action("Index","Packaging"));

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Call a controller? The controller shows the user a view and handles the result of the view.

Comment: Why would you need to have a separate handler for the button. The `Html.BeginForm("Create", "Packaging", FormMethod.Post)` already set to 'Packaging' controller and 'Create' action. The submit button will take care of the submission without having to create an event handler for it.

Comment: You also lose all other data in your form if your do it using `location.href` or `window.open`. This is what you should do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Packaging")" + "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to redirect the user to the Index action of the Packaging controller once details have been created.

You do this on the server side inside the Create action on the Packaging controller by return the following:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```